# as3 pepperFlash check on runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

How to check if flashPlayer version s pepperFlash on runtime?

I want to handle stage3d differently for pepperflash and differently for standard flash player version

Update:

I found one javascript function, so if anyone can help me to call it with ExternalInterface:

```
var checkForPepper = function() {
if (navigator.plugins) {
    for (var i=0, count = navigator.plugins.length; i < count; i++) {
        var filename = navigator.plugins[i].filename;
        if (filename === 'pepflashplayer.dll' || filename === 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin') return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update of your answer for more readable JS in AS3:

```
    var js:XML = <js>
        <![CDATA[
            function() {
                if (navigator.plugins) {
                    for (var i=0, count = navigator.plugins.length; i < count; i++) {
                        var filename = navigator.plugins[i].filename;
                        if (filename === 'pepflashplayer.dll' || filename === 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin') 
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;   
            }
        ]]>         
        </js>

        if(ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            var isPepper:Boolean = ExternalInterface.call(js);
            ExternalInterface.call("alert('isPepper = "+isPepper+"')");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how:

```
        _hasPepperFlash = String(ExternalInterface.call("function() {if (navigator.plugins) {for (var i = 0, count = navigator.plugins.length; i < count; i++){var filename = navigator.plugins[i].filename; if (filename === 'pepflashplayer.dll' || filename === 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin') return true; } } return false;} "))
```

Beware that it has to be in one line everything or it wont work. At least in my IDE IntelliJ